# How to reuse database connection without creating a new one in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class in PHP that creates a database connection using PDO approach and the class has methods that perform database actions like (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), etc.

The construct keyword creates a new connection to the MYSQL server whenever any database action is needed. This approach leads to "Too many connections" error and I wish to know if there's a way to detect if a connection is made already, then reuse that connection instead of establishing a new one.

Comment: Are you properly disposing of connections you used? Also, how about using singleton approach for connection management?

Comment: One common, modern approach is to use the dependency injection / inversion of control pattern - basically you pass a single copy of your class into all the places in your application which need it. The single instance can be created when your script first starts, and then re-used for the lifetime of the script.

Comment: **An alternative**: close your db connection upon script completion (actually this action should be automatic in most systems, but you may explicitly trigger it)

Comment: @KenLee that won't really help if the script is generating multiple unnecessary connections in the middle of it, which seems to be the case here. Even closing them down promptly won't be as effective as simply not creating them to begin with.

Comment: I was going to implement a way to close the DB connection after every database query. But I learned that there's another way to use active connection instead of reestablishing another one. 
Is this really possible?

Comment: @ADyson I use the require keyword to request for and use the class in all scripts that need to perform a database query. Does it still count?

Comment: It depends what's in the `require`'d script. If it's just the definition of the class then that doesn't actually create an instance or open the connection. So probably I'd guess you're creating multiple instances of the class, maybe even a new one every time you want to run a query. Instead you do what I suggested above - create once instance of the class at the beginning, and share it around.